# Is there a library for ActionScript 3 similar to jQuery touch for developing iPhone applications with Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Is there a library for ActionScript 3 similar to jQuery touch for developing iPhone applications with Flash?

Basically there is a jQuery library that emulates the native cocoa gui widgets with JavaScript for mobile websites, just wondering if there is something similar in Flash.

An acceptable answer would include, 'there isn't one'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research there doesn't appear to be a library that exists as of this point in time.

Answer (score 1):

Flex. The Flex 4.5.1 sdk gives you iPhone support. There are lots of UI elements that work pretty well and a lot more which need some more work to be usable. Mostly having to do with performance. In addition, Flextras has some mobile components available as well.